# How can I run extensionless CGI script from apache ROOT?

Tags: apache, configuration, cgi

I'm setting up an apache webserver (on Ubuntu 18.04) with a CGI script, but I want a clean URL without "cgi" in it.

I already have a functioning script (in Perl), which, for the purposes of this question, I'll call **`myscript`**.

## 1. `localhost/cgi-bin/myscript` (works)

If I put the script in `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/myscript`, it works with URL `localhost/cgi-bin/myscript`.

## 2. `localhost/myscript.cgi` (works)

Alternatively, I can reconfigure /var/www/ to run files with .cgi or .pl extensions as CGI:

```
 <Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
+    Options +ExecCGI
+    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
 </Directory>
```

This works **IF** I add a .cgi extention: `myscript.cgi`.  Then URL `localhost/myscript.cgi` works.

## 3. `localhost/myscript`  ???

But I don't want `cgi` in my URL.  I just want `localhost/myscript` to run `myscript` as CGI.  (And I don't want to force other files in ROOT to be CGI).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that directly. However, you could [Redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) requests for specific extension-less URLs to their corresponding .cgi.

You can test these with an `.htaccess` file to avoid having to reload the server.

In your `<VirtualHost ...>` section :

```
<Directory /your/web/dir/>
  Require all granted
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

In `/your/web/dir/.htaccess` :

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
Redirect  "/test" /test.cgi
# or
# RedirectMatch  "^/(test)$" /$1.cgi
```

Another possibility would be to use [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html), and redirect calls to any existing executable file to a file with the same name but with a .cgi extension. The extension-less file must only exist, and can be empty.

In `/your/web/dir/.htaccess` :

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

RewriteEngine On
# If not already .cgi and executable, redirect to .cgi
RewriteCond /your/web/dir/%{REQUEST_URI} "!\.cgi$"
RewriteCond /your/web/dir/%{REQUEST_URI} -x
RewriteRule ^(.+) /$1.cgi [R]
```

Of course, you can use any other extension than .cgi. For example `.x` if you set `AddHandler cgi-script .x`.